# I can preview but can't save scan with Epson L220

Tags: xubuntu, scanner, epson

I have installed Image-Scan software from [Epson support here](http://support.epson.net/linux/en/imagescanv3.php?version=1.3.18)  .
image-scan can detect my Epson L220 scanner, I can preview, I can click the <kbd>scan</kbd> button and a select folder to save the scan in progress. But I can't find the saved file. I have tried to run image-scan from user root, with the same result.

I'm using Xubuntu 16.04

Comment: Hi, I have encountered the same behaviour. Actually during the scan the file is there and I can even check its permissions. After the scan the file vanishes.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem using different scanner hardware (XP-960) using `imagescan`. What I did to solve this problem was to force the English language before running `imagescan`.

Go to a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type:

```
LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 
/usr/bin/imagescan
```

[Source](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=217894)

Comment: **jacco** Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** **jacco** and **@abu_bua** Please review my [edits](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1053839/revisions) and also review the [editing help](/editing-help) to improve the readability of your own answers / edits in the future.  **:-)**

Comment: I needed to add export to the environment variable: export LC_ALL=en_US.utf8

Answer (score 4):

The solution for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is not to set `LC_ALL=en_US.utf8`, as suggested in [another answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1053839/618353), but `LANG=en_US.utf8`:

```
$ LANG=en_US.utf8
$ /usr/bin/imagescan
```

Note that this means that you will run `imagescan` from the terminal and NOT from the icon provided by the application.

You can also run the above in one line as:

```
LANG=en_US.utf8 /usr/bin/imagescan
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/915635)

Comment: > This does not really answer the question: Answer: yes it will! but under Ubuntu 18 u have to set  the environment variable 'LANG' not 'LC_ALL'. The solution is to set this env variable before u call the programm. If u dont set the language definition to 'en_US.utf8' then u ll be able to use ur scanner (preview will work) but the file will not be saved. This is a bug in the scanner software from epson. And the lang setting is the solution for this bug.

Comment: Works for me. Thanks

Comment: Works on 18.04 (German), with new Epson printer/scanner.

Comment: Though I'll say that this is not so much a solution as a hack around the bug, which Epson really should fix properly...

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 18.04 and Epson L222.
I had same problem. After I changed my languages Formats to United States problem is solved (before this some remain ru_RU.UTF-8)