# Epson Perfection V19 scanner doesn't write scans to disc

Tags: 16.04, scanner, epson

After installing Epson driver (`imagescan-bundle-ubuntu-16.04-1.3.28.x86.deb.tar.gz`), Image Scan opens Scanning Dialog in which I can make preview, but when I order scanning, it shows window to choose type of file and choose place on disc to save it, but **after scanning** (scanner is working) **there is no file on disc**.

Using lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

**Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04b8:013c Seiko Epson Corp.** 

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

.
```

Using sane-find-scanner:

```
could not open USB device 0x1d6b/0x0003 at 002:001: Access denied (insufficient permissions)

**found USB scanner (vendor=0x04b8 [EPSON], product=0x013c) at libusb:001:003**

could not open USB device 0x1d6b/0x0002 at 001:001: Access denied (insufficient permissions)

.
```

xsane could not find any device.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I can preview but can't save scan with Epson L220](https://askubuntu.com/questions/897747/i-can-preview-but-cant-save-scan-with-epson-l220)

Comment: The current answers don't really address the question as it was asked (which is about the Epson program failing to _save scanned files_, and mostly unrelated to any driver problems). Correct answers to the question asked are here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/897747/i-can-preview-but-cant-save-scan-with-epson-l220

Answer (score 0):

in this post

[Epson GT-S50 scanner not working after upgrade to 18.04 from 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034528/epson-gt-s50-scanner-not-working-after-upgrade-to-18-04-from-16-04?noredirect=1#comment1687522_1034528)

that referred to a long bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sane-backends/+bug/1728012

it was recommended that one set up symbolic links

```
sudo ln -sfr /usr/lib/sane/libsane-epkowa* /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane
```

and create a **55-epson-libsane.rules** file in **/etc/udev/rules.d/**

if one uses gedit, Ubuntu is moving towards using

```
gedit admin:///etc/udev/rules.d/55-epson-libsane.rules
```

and that should open a blank file,(whose name is *55-epson-libsane.rules*) into which you paste the script in the above post; save; close; reboot

does any of this help?

Comment: My Xubuntu is 32 bit, so there is no such directory as **/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane** also **/usr/lib/sane** doesn't exist.  I made the file  **55-epson-libsane.rules** but it doesn't works. Scanner **makes preview and scans, but it not saves scan to a file**.

Comment: which version of ubuntu are you running please?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS

Answer (score 0):

When I made the file *55-epson-libsane.rules* with content taken from bug report (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sane-backends/+bug/1728012), I obtais strange situation: **Image Scan** (from Epson) still doesn't save files, **Simple Scan** (instaleed with Xubuntu) recognised scanner but doesn't scan, but **XSane Image scanning program** recognises scanner, scans and saves files to disc. It looks like funcionally problem is solved, but not completely until the end.